# Open A Bank Account In Another Country

Tags: banking

I'd like to take advantage of foreign currency rates. How can I get a bank account in foreign countries without visiting them?

Comment: As written, this is a duplicate of previous questions.  If you want to differentiate it, please tell us your country and the country where you want to open the account.